# Difference between "I have done" and "I have been doing"

Tags: sentence-meaning, past-perfect, past-simple

Please let me know the difference between here two sentences:

I have smoked for three years.

and

I have been smoking for three years.

Also if it started raining hours ago and now it doesn't (it has just stopped), can I say "It just rained for hours"? How should I say properly?

Answer (score 3):

> I have smoked for three years.

This talks about the past event of smoking. **But** it does not *exactly* says **when**. Today, if you say this to me, I'd understand that in past for any three years you smoked. Could be 2000-2003, 1990-93 or whichever 3 years you can guess.

> I have been smoking for three years

... means the smoking is *continued* and it has been three years i.e. you **started** smoking in October 2012 (three years from now in past).

And yes, you can say that for rain.

---

Recommended:

You may want to learn further on 'progressive tenses'. For this question, read here for [past perfect progressive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect_progressive.htm), [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect.htm#perfect) for past perfect and [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_perfect_progressive.htm) for present perfect progressive.

Comment: Thank you. I get it clearly. But if I've just stopped smoking today then how should I say to indicate that I started smoking in October 2012 but from now on I won't smoke anymore? I mean, is there a brief sentence to say that?

Comment: @maulik, you could edit it to add the tenses aspect...progressive etc.

Comment: @maulik : How the first one is different from "I smoked for three years"?

Comment: If you stopped it **today**, you may say - "I **had** been smoking for three years **till** yesterday*". If you put 'have' it connects it to the *present time* i.e. 'at present'.

Comment: @MamtaD okay, added.